# Migrating data using entity framework, linq and recursion

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, linq, entity-framework

I have a piece of code to migrate data from an old app to a new app. The data represents the user's websites.

In the old app the user only had one section for websites, on which you could add any website, even social links.

In the new app, the user can add personal websites, social links (only Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn are considered social links) and what we call custom social networks (eg. Reddit, Meetup, Tumblr, etc)

**This is the code:**

```
public async Task ImportWebsites(int userId)
{
    string[] socialNetworksStr =
    {
        "linkedin.",
        "twitter.",
        "facebook.",
    };

    string[] customSocialNetworksStr = 
    {   "deviantart.",
        "viadeo.",
        "reddit.",
        "xing.",
        "pinterest.",
        "tumblr.",
    };

    List<UserLinkDTO> personalWebsites = new List<UserLinkDTO>();
    List<UserSocialNetworkDTO> socialNetworks = new List<UserSocialNetworkDTO>();
    List<UserLinkDTO> customSocialNetworks = new List<UserLinkDTO>();
    List<UserLinkDTO> personalWebsitesRemoved = new List<UserLinkDTO>();


    using (OldContext ctx = new OldContext())
    {
        if (await (ctx.UserSettings.AnyAsync(u => u.UserId == userId)) == false)
            throw new RelatedEntityNotFoundException($"{userId} not be found!");

        personalWebsites = await ctx.PersonalWebsite.AsNoTracking()
                                    .Where(w => w.UserId == userId)
                                    .Select(w => new UserLinkDTO
                                    {
                                        UserId = w.UserId,
                                        Description = w.PersonalWebsiteDescription,
                                        Url = w.PersonalWebsiteURL,
                                        Name = w.PersonalWebsiteName
                                    }).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < personalWebsites.Count; i++)
    {
        string url = personalWebsites[i].Url;
        if (!url.StartsWith("http://"))
        {
            personalWebsites[i].Url = "http://" + url;
        }
    }

    if (personalWebsites.Any())
    {
        foreach (var personalWebsite in personalWebsites)
        {
            foreach (var socialNetwork in socialNetworksStr)
            {
                if (personalWebsite.Url.Contains(socialNetwork))
                {
                    socialNetworks.Add(new UserSocialNetworkDTO() {
                        SocialNetworkId = (short)(Array.IndexOf(socialNetworksStr, socialNetwork) + 1),
                        Account = personalWebsite.Url
                    });
                    personalWebsitesRemoved.Add(personalWebsite);
                }
            }
            foreach (var customSocialNetwork in customSocialNetworksStr)
            {
                if (personalWebsite.Url.Contains(customSocialNetwork))
                {
                    customSocialNetworks.Add(personalWebsite);
                    personalWebsitesRemoved.Add(personalWebsite);
                }
            }
        }

        personalWebsites = personalWebsites.Except(personalWebsitesRemoved).ToList();
        var personalInfo = await PersonalInfoService.GetPersonalInfo(userId);

        personalInfo.Result.PersonalWebsites = personalWebsites;
        if(socialNetworks.Any()) personalInfo.Result.SocialNetworks = socialNetworks;
        if(customSocialNetworks.Any()) personalInfo.Result.CustomSocialNetworks = customSocialNetworks;

        var response = await PersonalInfoService.SavePersonalInfo(personalInfo.Result);
    }
}

    var response = await PersonalInfoService.SavePersonalInfo(personalInfo.Result);
}
```

My code does its job, but it takes some time, on those foreaches, and I think it's a little bit redundant, and I think it may be optimzed. How would you improve this?

**PS** I think I included all the necessary info, sorry If I forgot something.

Comment: Could you post the complete method? I don't see any recursion there.

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, your foreach loops are O(n^2).

Comment: @t3chb0t there's not much more left, I've edited the code. Thanks for the interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reducing loops

You iterate over the `personalWebistes` two times.

First here in the `for` loop

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < personalWebsites.Count; i++)
> ```

and once agian in the `foreach`

> ```
> foreach (var personalWebsite in personalWebsites)
> ```

but this is not necessary. You can do everything with only one loop by adding the `http://` prefix in the second loop iterating over the `personalWebsites` only once.

---

Btw. I'll remove this check first because it's not necessary:

> ```
> if (personalWebsites.Any())
> ```

If the collection is empty then the loop simply won't run even once. You use a list here so `Any()` doesn't do any harm but if you had a deferred `IEnumerable` the it would *execute* it. If it performs some *heavy* work this could be very bad for ther performance.

---

I'll also remove the `personalWebsitesRemoved` because you don't need this one either. You can save the results directly into the final list that I call `websitesWithoutSocial`. I use this new list inside the `else` block. If you've found the url you can `break` the inner loop. There's no point in checking other addresses.

```
var websitesWithoutSocial = new List<UserLinkDTO>();

foreach (var personalWebsite in personalWebsites)
{
    var url = personalWebsite.Url;

    if (!url.StartsWith("http://"))
    {
        url = $"http://{url}";
    }

    var isSocial = false;

    foreach (var socialNetwork in socialNetworks)
    {
        if ((isSocial = url.Contains(socialNetwork)))
        {
            socialNetworks.Add(new UserSocialNetworkDTO()
            {
                SocialNetworkId = (short)(Array.IndexOf(socialNetworks, socialNetwork) + 1),
                Account = personalWebsite.Url
            });
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isSocial) { continue; }

    foreach (var customSocialNetwork in customSocialNetworks)
    {
        if ((isSocial = url.Contains(customSocialNetwork)))
        {
            customSocialNetworks.Add(personalWebsite);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isSocial) { continue; }

    websitesWithoutSocial.Add(personalWebsite);
}
```

Now that everything is already separated into multiple lists you also don't need the `Except` and you can save the results right away:

```
var personalInfo = (await PersonalInfoService.GetPersonalInfo(userId)).Result;

personalInfo.PersonalWebsites = websitesWithoutSocial;
personalInfo.SocialNetworks = socialNetworks;
personalInfo.CustomSocialNetworks = customSocialNetworks;

var response = await PersonalInfoService.SavePersonalInfo(personalInfo);
```

---

## Using Parallel.ForEach

If even with the *simple* improvements this is still *slow* you can try to use the `Parallel.ForEach` but be careful. You need to use different collections that are thread-safe. This should further improve the performance.

Here's an example:

```
var websitesWithoutSocial = new BlockingCollection<UserLinkDTO>();
var socalNetworks = new BlockingCollection<UserLinkDTO>();
var customSocialNetworks = new BlockingCollection<UserLinkDTO>();

Parallel.ForEach(personalWebsites, website => 
{
    var url = personalWebsite.Url;

    if (!url.StartsWith("http://"))
    {
        url = $"http://{url}";
    }

    foreach (var socialNetwork in socialNetworks)
    {
        if (url.Contains(socialNetwork))
        {
            socialNetworks.Add(new UserSocialNetworkDTO()
            {
                SocialNetworkId = (short)(Array.IndexOf(socialNetworks, socialNetwork) + 1),
                Account = personalWebsite.Url
            });
            return;
        }
    }

    foreach (var customSocialNetwork in customSocialNetworks)
    {
        if (url.Contains(customSocialNetwork))
        {
            customSocialNetworks.Add(personalWebsite);
            return;
        }
    }

    websitesWithoutSocial.Add(personalWebsite);
});
```

You'll find the `BlockingCollection<T>` in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

With the `Parallel.ForEach` loop you don't need the `isSocial` helper because the body is an `Action` (an anonymous method, a delegate) so you can safely `return` and skip the rest of it.

---

## RelatedEntityNotFoundException

> ```
> if (await (ctx.UserSettings.AnyAsync(u => u.UserId == userId)) == false)
> {
>   throw new RelatedEntityNotFoundException($"{userId} not be found!");
> }
> ```

This method shouldn't check the user-id. If it doesn't exist then the method won't do anything useful. Check the user-id before calling `ImportWebsites`.

---

## Any

Lastly you can rewrite the inner loops and the `isSocial` workaround with LINQ:

```
if (socialNetworkNames.Any(x => url.Contains(x))
{
    socialNetworks.Add(new UserSocialNetworkDTO()
    {
        SocialNetworkId = (short)(Array.IndexOf(socialNetworks, socialNetwork) + 1),
        Account = personalWebsite.Url
    });
    continue;
}


if (customSocialNetworkNames.Any(x => url.Contains(x))
{
    customSocialNetworks.Add(personalWebsite);
    continue;
}

websitesWithoutSocial.Add(personalWebsite);
```

If you use this snippen in the `Parallel.ForEach` you may also replace the `continue` with `return`.

Comment: Great answer, complete and educative. Do you need `if(isSocial) { continue; }` if it's a parallel foreach? (which would be `if(isSocial) { return; }` in a parralel foreach)

Comment: @SGN you're right, you don't need it the `Parallel.ForEach` because the body is an `Action` (an anonymous method) - but I suggest you use the `Any` solution without the inner loops. I find this is easier to understand but even there in the parallel loop you can use `return`. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @SGN I hope you could improve the perfomance with this at least a little bit ;-)

Comment: @SGN yes, this can happen because there's a lot of synchronization inside it. This is hard to predict how good or bad it will perform because it depends on how the various urls are distributed. I included it for completnes so that you can try it out. I think there is no easier way to split those urls in various categories programatically. Should it be super-fast then you'll need to change the database models to store the relevant url part as a column and join it with another table that has them categorized. This would outperform everything else but I don't know if it's an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is `O(n^2)`. More precisely, it's Theta(n^2) because it'll always be exactly `n`.

```
foreach (var personalWebsite in personalWebsites)
{
    // You can use a HashSet to eliminate the need for the inner loops, which
    // would reduce your computational complexity from Theta(n^2) to Theta(n) - see below
    foreach (var socialNetwork in socialNetworksStr)
    {
        // You could "convert" both of these to some kind of "normal form" (see below) to eliminate the need for the relatively inefficient "Contains" and enable the use of a HashSet
        if (personalWebsite.Url.Contains(socialNetwork))
        {
            socialNetworks.Add(new UserSocialNetworkDTO() { SocialNetworkId = (short)(Array.IndexOf(socialNetworksStr, socialNetwork) + 1), Account = personalWebsite.Url });
            personalWebsitesRemoved.Add(personalWebsite);

            // If you do stick with a loop here, presumably each personal web site only
            // matches one social media site, so you can break out of the loop here to
            // improve your computational complexity for this bit from Theta(n) to O(n)
        }
    }

    // Same comments as above
    foreach (var customSocialNetwork in customSocialNetworksStr)
    {
        if (personalWebsite.Url.Contains(customSocialNetwork))
        {
            customSocialNetworks.Add(personalWebsite);
            personalWebsitesRemoved.Add(personalWebsite);
        }
    }
```

You can reduce this to O(n) by reducing the URLs to some kind of "normal form" (e.g. http://www.linkedin.com/in/some.person would just be "normalized" to "linkedin.com") and building a Dictionary (hash table) or [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx). This would reduce the computational complexity from Theta(n^2) to Theta(n).

Also, even if you do stick with the "inner" foreach loops, there's no need to iterate over all of the social network sites every single time; I assume that each personal web site can only match one social media site, so if you find one that it matches it reduces the computational complexity from Theta(n^2) to O(n^2).

Comment: Thank you very much, i do admit, i do not know how to use a hashset, or how to get a O(n^2) from Theta(n^2), but everything sounds valid. I will get back to you once I acomplish your recomandations

Comment: @SGN It's very similar to using a hash table/dictionary. In terms of the computational complexity, remember that Theta(n) means "exactly n" whereas O(n) means "*at worst* n".